# X given Y is a normal random variable with mean Y and var 4. Y~Binomial(10, 0.6). Find E(X) and Var(X)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, continuous-data, variable

Is this a joint probability distribution? Can I assume X and Y are independent and that E(XY)=Y? I am stuck at this question.

Comment: It is illogical to assume something that contradicts what the problem assumes: after all, since the mean of $X$ depends on $Y,$ $X$ and $Y$ cannot possibly be independent.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a problem that benefits greatly from the laws of total expectation and variance (which essentially are two formulas):

$$
E(X) = E(E(X|Y)) = EY  = 10*0.6 = 6
$$

$$
Var(X) = E(Var(X|Y)) + Var(E(X|Y)) \\ = E(4) + Var(Y) \\= 4 + 10*0.6*0.4 \\= 4 + 2.4 = 6.4
$$

So, $E(X)$ is 6 and $Var(X)$ is 6.4.

HTH.